# How to change behavior according to other macro defined later?

Tags: macros, m4

Suppose I have a file `tools.m4` with macro definitions:

```
define([YEAR_2_DIGITS], substr(YEAR, [2], [2]))
```

I want to use in another file `query.sql`:

```
changequote(`[', `]')
include(./tools.m4)

define([YEAR], [2017])

YEAR_2_DIGITS
```

But obviously it will return:

```
$ m4 query.sql


AR
```

instead of `17`.

Is there a workaround to make that construct work?

Comment: How is this related to the <sql> _language_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it. One has to quote the body of the first definition:

```
define([YEAR_2_DIGITS], [substr(YEAR, [2], [2])])
```